# How to use an already scanned QR Code in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, expo, qr-code

I'm currently using the *BarCodeScanner* from **expo-barcode-scanner** and after reading a QR Code I console.log its type and data like this:

Bar code with type org.iso.QRCode and data WIFI:T:WPA;S:Vodafone-964***;P:QX6wDqw***;; has been scanned!

For this case, since it's a wi-fi connection, I can't use Linking.openURL(), but I wanted to make use of the code in my app in order to the user enter in the WI-FI.

Is there a function to use this type of codes beside links in react-native?